# In Scala, how do I get a column from a dataframe while keeping its data type?

Tags: scala

Simple question, but I'm a bit of a Scala novice. I have the following dataframe:

```
scala> output.printSchema
root
 |-- sen: string (nullable = true)
 |-- words: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- lemma: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- pos: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I am attempting to apply the zip function to the **words** and **lemma** columns as follows:

```
scala> output("words") zip output("lemma")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
<console>:44: error: value zip is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

How do I retrieve the **words** and **lemma** columns as array of strings? I've tried a few things but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `collect()`

See docs here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

***collect(): Array[T]
 Permalink
Returns an array that contains all of Rows in this Dataset.***

```
val results = output.collect()
```